# Shell scripting, search and replace by a variable

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a small sql file which has a place holder pattern for date. For example a file `t.sql`

```
select count(*) from tablename where date >= STARTDATE
```

I want to replace STARTDATE above with the present date from a shell script. For example what I have is the following

```
DATE=`date +%Y%m%d`
sed -e "s/STARTDATE/\$DATE/g" t.sql
```

However, this simply replaces STARTDATE with $DATE. How do I force `sed` to use the value of this variable? Or is there another way in say Perl?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need not escape the `$` in sed

```
sed -e "s/STARTDATE/$DATE/g" t.sql
```

**Test**

```
$ echo "select count(*) from tablename where date >= STARTDATE" | sed -e "s/STARTDATE/$DATE/g"
select count(*) from tablename where date >= 20141220
```

Answer (score 2):

I recognize you were asking for how to do this in the Shell, and I see you've already received several excellent answers, but a better overall design would be to do the query in native SQL. Almost every major vendor offers a mechanism to query based on today's date. For example, In MySQL

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename WHERE DATE(date) >= DATE(NOW())
```

Comment: also prevents any conceivable sql injection

Answer (score 1):

Don't escape the dollor($).

```
sed -e "s/STARTDATE/$DATE/g" t.sql
```

Or else you can use the echo inside the substitution.

```
sed -e "s/STARTDATE/`echo $DATE`/g"
```